How to add ofetch/$fetch Request Options?
How to add types to default options so that they are displayed correctly?
import type { FetchOptions } from 'ofetch'

type ApiFetchOptionsExtra = {
    skipAuthTokenProcessing?: boolean
    preventLogout?: boolean
}

type ApiFetchOptions = FetchOptions & ApiFetchOptionsExtra // this

const api = $fetch.create({
    baseURL: apiUrl,
    async onRequest({ options }) {
        options.preventLogout = true // here 1
        // ...
    },
    // ...
})

api('asd', {
    body: ...,
    preventLogout: true, // here 2
})


Found such a solution:
declare module 'ofetch' {
    interface ResolvedFetchOptions extends ApiFetchOptionsExtra {
    }

    interface FetchOptions extends ApiFetchOptionsExtra {
    }
}

